# Install Ubuntu along Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, operating-systems, multi-boot

I have Windows 7 installed on my PC. Now I need to install Ubuntu as a second OS. I googled the same and got some sites that give the option of installing either by downloading Ubuntu, making a CD and creating customized partition OR by downloading `WUBI.exe`.

The WUBI way is pretty simple and I wish to go that way but the links ([here](https://wiki.Ubuntu.com/WubiGuide)) suggest that the installation drive should be C Drive. Is that mandatory? What if I consider some other drive as installation drive (say E drive)?

If the answer to above questions is YES, do I need to backup that drive? Also, if the installation size is 8 GB, for e.g. than would that drive be partitioned? Or just a folder would be created?

Comment: he beat me to an answer but thought I would add....The newest version of ubuntu lets you run from a CD before you install if you wanted to test.

Comment: Yes @harper89, you can try but i need to install

Comment: If you have the resources for it, try http://www.virtualbox.org/ first. You can install various Operating Systems as Virtual Machines without partitioning your hard drive. Each OS install is just a single (large) file unto itself.

Comment: Use VirtualBox to install it as VM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is ALWAYS a good idea to backup your computer when doing an OS install, whether it is technically required or not.

Your link shows a drop down menu for WUBI, so you can likely install it on whatever drive you want to.

<del>WUBI installs Ubuntu onto a separate partition, not just into a folder. (so yes, your drive would be partitioned)</del>

> Wubi adds an entry to the Windows boot
>   menu which allows the user to run
>   Linux. Ubuntu is installed within a
>   file in the Windows file system
>   (c:\ubuntu\disks\root.disk), as
>   opposed to being installed within its
>   own partition. This file is seen by
>   Linux as a real hard disk.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wubi_%28Ubuntu_installer%29) Wubi
>   also creates a swap file in the
>   Windows file system
>   (c:\ubuntu\disks\swap.disk), in
>   addition to the memory of the host
>   machine. This file is seen by Ubuntu
>   as additional RAM.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wubi_%28Ubuntu_installer%29)

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wubi_%28Ubuntu_installer%29)

Comment: @viking, it is ALWAYS a good idea to back up your computer ... whether or not you are doing an OS install. :-)

Comment: @CarlF Can't argue with that.

Comment: http://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-11-04-with-windows-7/ This says NOT to install on C-Drive (mean Windows drive)

Comment: so i believe partition is not created if i install in say E drive? Just files are created as you mention..correct?

Comment: If the partition is shown in Windows as "E" then it is already a Windows partition. Installing Ubuntu there would mean deleting the partition, creating a new Windows partition, and reformatting it (probably as ext4). This would mean losing all the data on the current E: drive.

Comment: no C Drive is my windows OS partition.. E drive is just another drive..contains data and other stuff..

Comment: so if i now select E drive as installation drive while installing via wubi.. it won't be partitioning E drive right???

Comment: @romilnagrani that is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can either install it directly on your Windows partition or another drive.  IF you install on drive you'll probably need to replace the bootloader with a Linux compatible one like grub.

Comment: If i do NOT install in C Drive--My Windows drive and select any other drive, then i believe a boot loader is not needed.. correct?